# Broken link for Job Alerts in user profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, broken-link, stack-overflow-jobs, newsletter

I found a broken link in `Edit Profile & Settings > Email Settings > Newsletters`, the link for Job Alerts is wrong as:

`https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts?`

In all other sections of the Edit Profile & Settings the link is correct (finishing with the user number):

`https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/[user-number]`